# Searching for keywords in a string efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, string, substring

```
m = "a1 - a2 - a3" #stored in database 

n = "a4 - a5" #given by user
```

"-" is just a seperator I used while making the database to make things orderly

I have many strings like these and what I am trying to do is *check* whether **n** is **in** **m**.

```
if n.lower() in m.lower():
```

This is what I have right now.

```
m = "a - b - c" #example

n = "b - c" #given by user
```

This will return True and it seemed to me that everything worked out fine.

```
m = "a - b - c" #example

n = "c - b" #given by user
```

But I want this to return True too. Order shouldn't be concerned.

Tldr; I am trying to find multiple words/characters in a string but the order shouldn't matter.

```
def search(userString, dbString):
    userString.lower()
    dbString.lower()
    for i in dbS.split():
        for j in userS.split():
            if j in i:
```

I tried something like this but I really don't know how to proceed.

Comment: So is it simply checking if some letters are in a string (i.e. `all(i in m for i in n.split(" - "))`)?

Comment: Wow it is actually almost working. But it didn't work for m=a4 & n = "a5 - a4" 
I think "-" becomes necessary for it to work? (I didn't know split could do that though)

Comment: So the separator can change?

Comment: I have only two separators and also sometimes there might not be any separator. I am really sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Comment: Don't worry ;) So when there's no separator, it is like `"a5a4"`?

Comment: n = a4 & m = a5 - a4 
I mistyped them before

Anyway my problem has been solved thanks to you all <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = "a - b - c"
n = "c - b"
flag = False
array = n.split()
for elem in array:
    if elem not in m:
        flag = True
if flag is True:
    print("Not a sub string")
```